# How to add a node from one linked list onto another

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to remove a 'card' (node) from a linked list called deck and move it onto the player's hand. Overall, this is where a player would be drawing a card so the card would be added to their hand and completely deleted from the deck. I viewed [Linked Lists: Moving a node from one linked list to the next](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20636265/5870908) and tried to follow this format along with a modified format of my dealing cards function. Unfortunately, my function is not outputting anything. I have modified this function many different times, but I think the problem lies with allocating the memory to a new space in the hand. I also tried pointer-to-pointers for hand and deck because that solved many of the other problems in my code, but my method did not seem to make a difference. Here is my most recent attempt. It is definitely one of my more complicated attempts for whenever I edit it, I just seem to add more lines of code.

```
void drawCard (card* hand, card* deck) {
   card* newCard = NULL;
   newCard = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card*));
   deck = deck->listp;
   newCard = hand;
   while (hand != NULL) {
      hand = hand->listp;
   }
   newCard->face = deck->face;
   newCard->suit = deck->suit;
   hand = newCard->listp;

}
```

My idea while writing this is I move the deck to the next position in the list (the first position is the "Top Card" in play) and that will be card for drawing. I then set newCard equal to the first position of hand, and then move hand to the very end of the list. I thought this would open a spot up at the top of player's hand, but I seem to be mistaken. Also, I realized I did not add a section to delete the node from the deck. Would I just create a temp variable, copy the card node to the temp, and then free it from the deck? Any guidance would be very appreciated.

Comment: Your call to `malloc` is using the wrong size.  You need `sizeof(card)`, not `sizeof(card *)`.  This is a segmentation fault just waiting to happen.

Comment: `newCard = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card*));` then `newCard = hand;` causes a serious memory leak. You are allocating a memory for `NewCard` and then subsequently losing track of it.

Comment: Thank you @TomKarzes! I completely missed that extra asterisk.

Comment: @alvits that would explain the bad access error. Unfortunately though my many attempts to fix this function I ended up just making it worse by losing track of memory! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what your really asking but you need to remove and free a node you want to keep track of where you are in the list and bypass that node **then** free it

```
card * current = list -> head;
card * next_node = current -> next;
 /* To delete the next node*/
current->next = next_node-> next;
free(next_node->data);
free(next_node);
```

To move a node from one list to another its just a matter of finding your insertion point in list1 (strcmp?) then you can iterate over list2 finding the node you wish to move, you dont need to memove or free at this stage you need to set pointers to it

```
node2 -> next = node1 -> next;
node1 -> next = &node2;
```

list contains the head

```
 struct list
 {
     node * head;
     struct data * card_data;
 }
```

to use this linked list I would  have nodes

```
 struct *node
 {
     struct data * card_data; /*contains the details of this card*/
     node * next; /* pointer to the next node*/
 }
```

itterate in the following way assuming you have initialized he node (each pointer needs to be malloc'd)

```
node cur = list ->head;
if (cur == NULL)
{ 
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
do
{

    /* some check on the node */
    cur =  cur- > next;
    next = cur -> next;
}while (next != NULL)
```

Comment: I am a little confused with your format here. I have never seen pointing to a node in a list in this kind of format `card* current = list -> head;`. Are you just saying that the current should be set to the head of the list? Also, why would I not want to free a node in the second stage? I want to delete that node anyway; why could these two steps not be done in the same function?

Comment: what is your list structure? in the title you have said you wish to copy a node to another list if thats the case you are simply getting the pointer to point to the address of the node. I will add an example of how I would use this let me know if that doesn't clarify

Comment: My list structure is `struct card_s { char suit; int face; struct card_s *listp; }card;` but i think that clarified it! thank you so much!

Comment: let me know if you need help on the initialization/freeing  otherwise good luck with it mate